# REST API POST call - accepting list of objects

Tags: rest

Typically the POST call takes a single object, creates that object and returns the Id. 
However, I am encountering a business need that requires us to take a **list of objects in a single POST** call. Also, referred to as bulk POST. 
The question is ... what are the best practices to provide such kind of functionality --

1. Is it good practice to process these kind of request ***synchronously or asynchronously***?
2. Should implementation of this API limit the acceptable max list size?
3. The SLA of API will get impacted as the size of list increases (if the process is synchronous). How should this be addressed?

Any **thoughts/ideas/suggestions** will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what kind object are you expecting? String, Number , file or anything else?

Comment: It's a list of JSON objects. A single JSON object itself has 20 key value pairs in it

Comment: 1. asynchronously. 2. yes. 3. see #1.

Comment: Do you have any reference to public APIs accepting controlled lists as the payload for POST?